# How to convert categorical values into columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am working with a dataset that is structured like the one below. As you can see, the *indicator* column contains binary categorical data.

```
country_code    indicator   cumulative_count
AFG             cases       52909
AFG             deaths      2230
...             ...         ...
```

I would like to turn the *indicator* column into two separate columns (corresponding with the values of *indicator*: *cases* and *deaths*). I.e. I'm expecting the final result to be like this:

```
country_code    cases   deaths
AFG             52909   2230
...             ...     ...
```

Notes:

- The original dataset is publically accessible from [ECDC website](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/geographical-distribution-2019-ncov-cases).
- I am only interested in the *cumulative_count* of one specific *year_week* (2020-53).
- Here is a screenshot of the dataset:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Load your data table into Excel
- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Read in the table
//Change table name in next line to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    //Remove the unneeded columns
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"country_code", "indicator", "year_week", "cumulative_count"}),

//Set the data types for those columns
    #"Set Data Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{
        {"country_code", type text}, {"indicator", type text},{"year_week", type text},{"cumulative_count", Int64.Type}
    }),

//Pivot the Indicator column and aggregate by Sum
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Set Data Type", 
        List.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"[indicator]), "indicator", "cumulative_count", List.Sum),

//Filter to show only the relevant year-week for rows where thiere is a country_code
//  (the others refer to continents)
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Pivoted Column", each ([country_code] <> null) and ([year_week] = "2020-53"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

***filtered to show just 2020-53***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly. one way:
Add new column F
Formula in $F$2: sumifs($D2:$D$9999, $B2:$B$9999, $B2, $E2:$E$9999, "deaths")

copy formula down through end record
filter column E for "cases"

if you then insert rows above the header row, you can use Subtotal(109, ...) to view cumulative counts for a specific year, or alternatively add another column with Sumif as shown above